# In Julia, Plot a graph with specific sub labels

Tags: plot, julia, axis-labels

This question was posted in other forum:
https://discourse.julialang.org/t/plot-a-graph-with-specific-sub-labels/68491

I need plot something with a particular axis labels. More specifically, sub-labels.

First, I'm gointo to plot the standar plot:

```
tg = 0:0.001:0.7
points = rand(size(tg)[1])

sublabels =  fill("Julia", size(tg)[1] )
tab = [tg points]
sublabels[ tab[:,1] .<= 0.2 ] .= "A"
sublabels[ 0.2 .< tab[:,1] .<= 0.6 ] .= "B"
sublabels[ 0.6 .< tab[:,1] .<= 0.7 ] .= "C"
tab = [tab sublabels]


plot(tab[:,1], tab[:,2], xlabel = "tax")
```

I would like to keep this graph and add these sub labels according to the last column of the matrix tab. The limits of these ranges must be highlighted. I would also like to keep the main "tax" label.

Some help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy-paste of my answer on discourse:

A hacky solution is

```
xlims = (-0.05, 0.75)
plot(tab[:,1], tab[:,2]; xlabel="tax", xticks=[0.0, 0.2, 0.6, 0.7], xlims)
plot!([NaN], [NaN]; label="", yticks=[],
    xticks=([0.1, 0.4, 0.65], ["A", "B", "C"]), tick_direction=:none,
    grid=:none,
    inset = (1, bbox(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, :bottom, :right)),
    subplot = 2,
    bg_inside = nothing, xlims
)
```

and gives

[image]